# How to prevent single quote in th:onclick getting escaped when using thymeleaf

Tags: thymeleaf

I want to get `onclick="alert('myvar')"` in the browser.

I tried

```
th:onclick="'alert(\'' + ${myVar} + '\');'"
```

and I got

```
onclick="alert(&#39;null&#39;);"
```

I tried

```
th:onclick="|alert('${myVar}');|"
```

and I still got

```
onclick="alert(&#39;null&#39;);"
```

How can I let the single quote not be escaped?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following snipped worked for me:

```
th:onclick="|alert('${myVar}');|"
```

That looks like your second attemp but I'm getting:

```
onclick="alert('null');"
```

That makes me thinking and I tested your first attemp:

```
th:onclick="'alert(\'' + ${myVar} + '\');'"
```

and again I'm getting:

```
onclick="alert('null');"
```

Spooky! I searched for similar questions in the thymleaf-forum afterwards and that's the way how to to this.

Comment: So that's maybe a question related with configuration or version of thymeleaf. 
Would you help to try http://itutorial.thymeleaf.org/exercise/12 , add `th:onclick="|alert('${myVar}');|"` to the submit button and see if it shows `onclick="alert(&#39;null&#39;);"`

Comment: Shows &#39: but that isn't a problem since &#39; is the decimal name of the entity '. The editor-like window on the right side just shows you the entities decimal name.

Comment: Yes, it works rightly just like what I need. I thought `&#39;` in `onclick` would be a syntax error before. Thank you very much.